# can my niece travel to the uk using her greek id card after brexit

Tags: uk, eu-citizens, brexit

my niece is due to travel for a visit in April 2019 for 3 weeks to the uk and we are a bit concerned about what travel documents she can travel on due to the uk leaving the EU with or without a deal on the 29th of march any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note, till Brexit is active all advise is speculation.

Comment: No one knows. It's all up in the air right now.

Comment: This sets out the current position https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-after-brexit

Comment: @Willeke Is that really a duplicate? The guidance on https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-after-brexit seems definitive, unlike the answers given in the suggested duplicate

Comment: @Traveller That is the problem with Brexit related questions, non of the answers is guarantied to be right. This seemed the best fit but if you can give be a link to an other question here that is a better fit, I will re-open and close as duplicate of that other question.